# unable to access http://ip:7474 running on ec2 from elastic beanstalk running php

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running neo4j on ec2 instance and I can see it running on http://ip:7474/browser on ec2 .I am unable to access it via php on elastic beanstalk.The path to the file displays blank page.

I have also added the public-ip of elastic beanstalk instance to linux ami instance as CUSTOM TCP.Is there someting I am missing? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$data2 ='CREATE (Person:Person {name:”test”}) RETURN Person';
$data2 = array("query" =>$data2);
$data_string = json_encode($data2);


$ch = curl_init('http://aws_ip:7474/db/data/cypher');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that any security groups that your instance is attached to have a rule that allows inbound TCP on 7474.

Also make sure that your `Dockerrun.aws.json` file is configured correctly.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "kbastani/docker-neo4j",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "7474"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/neo4j/data",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/opt/data"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I did that but I still get blank page.No value is created on neo4j.

Comment: Please update your question with your Dockerrun.aws.json. One that is correctly configured has been updated as a part of my answer.